# PIL Drawing text and breaking lines at \n

Tags: python-3.x, text, python-imaging-library, draw

Hi im having some trouble getting sometimes longer texts which should be line breaked at specific lines onto an image it always just prints  the \n with it without breaking the line and i cant find any info online if this is even possible or if it just sees the raw string to put on the img without checking for linebreaks. The Text is just some random stuff from a CSV

```
    def place_text(self,text,x,y):

    temp = self.csv_input[int(c)][count]
    font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 35)  # font z.b.: arial.ttf
    w_txt, h_txt = font.getsize(text)

    print("Jetzt sind wie in der zweiten möglichkeit")
    draw_text = ImageDraw.Draw(self.card[self.cardCount])
    draw_text.text((x, y), temp, fill="black", font=font, align="left")
```

Yeah i know this Code is kinda all over the place but for putting the text on the image that shouldnt cause any issues does it?

Writing stuff on an Imgae with that results in just one line of continuous text with the \n's still in there and no line breaks.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Something like `draw.text((20, 20), 'Line1\nLine2\nLine3', fill=(0, 0, 0), font=font)` works perfectly fine for me (Python 3.9.1, Pillow 8.2.0). Please provide a [mre]. Maybe there's something fishy in the rest of your code.

Comment: Hey i've updated it a bit it is used to place some text on a tkinter canvas and somehow doesnt do it. i checked the text coming from the csv it has all \n's but just places them with it instead of breaking the lines

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer the String pulled fomr the CSV had to be decoded again before beeing placed
text = bytes(text, 'utf-8').decode("unicode_escape")
did the trick